# Socket Client always connects to localhost

Tags: c++, sockets

I have a problem where my client always seems to connect to localhost(127.0.0.1) even though I'm passing it another address. Consider:
$ ./client 139.130.4.5 80

```
    if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1 ){
       error("Opening Socket");
    }
    if ( (server = gethostbyname(argv[1])) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        close(sockfd);
        exit(0);
    }
    memset((char *) &serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    memcpy((char *)server->h_addr, (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portnum);

    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) == -1){
        error("Connect", sockfd);
    }
```

This always results in a connection to localhost, even though `argv[1]` is 139.130.4.5 and `portnum` is 80

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In memcpy() function:

```
#include <string.h>
void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n);
```

The first argument is destination, the second is the source, so instead of

```
memcpy((char *)server->h_addr, (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);
```

you should write

```
memcpy( &serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_addr, server->h_length);
     // ^ as Adam pointed out, no (char*) here
```

Answer (score 2):

You have the arguments to [`memcpy(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy) backwards.  It should be `memcpy(dest, source, len)`:

```
memcpy(&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_addr, server->h_length);
```

Also, you shouldn't be casting to `char *` in the calls to `memcpy()` and `memset()`, since they take `void*` as arguments, and any pointer type can be implicitly converted to `void*` without a cast.  The cast just clutters up the code and could hide a potential bug (like trying to pass in a non-pointer type).